# Measuring voltage in VFD

Tags: vfd

I an troubleshooting my chiller because I fried my compressor. I have done clues of what could go wrong, but want to discard over voltage. I have a Mitsubishi VFD. That I take 240 and convert to 240 3 phase. But when I measure 1 get 176 and between lines I get 380. But the VFD is program to 240 60 Hz. Do I need a diferent meter?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! _"That I take 240 and convert to 240 3 phase"_ Do you mean it takes 240 V single phase and converts to 240 V 3 phase? _"But when I measure 1 get 176"_ Do you mean when you measure phase 1 to neutral you get 176 V RMS? Do you have a true-RMS meter? Are you measuring under load?

Comment: I believe  is  not  an RMS meter my measurements are in stby.  and full load

Comment: meter was bought at sears

Comment: And my first two questions? “In standby and under full load”, does that mean the measurements are the same?